# Finding limit with log with base x

Tags: limits, logarithms

Let $k$ and $j$ be positive numbers. $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \log_{x^j} x^k$$

$\log_{x^j} x^k=\frac{\ln x^k}{\ln x^j}=\frac {k \ln x}{j \ln x}$. So, the $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \log_{x^j} x^k=\frac{k}{j}$$.

Is that right? I did not use the fact $j$ and $k$ are positive

Comment: Yes, this is correct. (By the way, you can typeset logarithms using `\log_{base}` and `\ln`)

Comment: You do not need $k$ and $j$ to be positive, but  you do need $x$ to be positive to have a real logarithm and you need $x \not=1$ and $j\not =0$  to avoid division by $0$.  Since your limit is as $x\to \infty$, the only substantial requirement is $j\not=0$

Comment: And indeed, you actually showed that $\log_{x_j}x^k = \frac kj$ is _constant_, which is even stronger than calculating the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You seem bang on target. You have used the so-called change of the base property of logarithms.

$$\log_x y=\frac{\log_b y}{\log_b x}$$ for any appropriate $b>0$.

Note that, as mentioned in the comments too, $k,j$ need not be positive.